# How to run Grunt Copy Task automatically when our project run

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I want to copy some files from one folder to another automatically when my project start.Now I do it by run a command in cmd "grunt copy". Please help me on this.

My Gruntfile.js Code:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
        copy: {
            t1: {
                src: 'Scripts/**',
                dest:'Target/'
            }
        } 
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'copy:t1');
};
```

Comment: What does "when my project start" mean?

Comment: I mean, When I run my project by pressing Ctrl+F5, Then grunt task should automatically completed So that I need not to run command from cmd again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy:t1']);